# Is this Field extension algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K \subset{L}$ be a field extension, and let $x,y \in{L}$ be trascendental elements. Is $K(2x+y,x+2y)$ algebraic over K?

The case of $\operatorname{char}(K)\neq 3$ is pretty straightforward, if it was algebraic, the fact that algebraic elements are a field together with $2x+y-2(x+2y)=-3y$  would make $y$ algebraic over $K$ , a clear contradiction.

However, the same trick doesn't work on fields of characteristic 3 and I am stuck.

Comment: If $\mathrm{char}(K) = 3$, then $K(2x+y, x+2y) = K(x-y)$. If $x$ is transcendental over $K$, then $x+1$ also. Pick $y = x+1$.

Comment: In a field of characteristic $3,$ you get $x+2y=-(2x+y).$ So $K(x+2y,2x+y)=K(x+2y).$ You can even get $x+2y=0,$ so it is possible for $K(x+2y)$ to be algebraic over $K.$

Comment: @halbaroth do you mean y=-x+1 ? I guess that would make it K(2x+1)=K(x) which is trascendental.

Comment: If $y = x+1$, you obtain $K(x-y) = K(x-(x+1)) = K(-1) = K$, which is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: @SamueleMonitto If $y=x+1$ in characteristic $3$, then $2x+y=3x+1=1$ so $x, y$ transcendental over $K$ is not enough to guarantee that $K(2x+y, x+2y)$ is transcendental over $K$.

Comment: @RobertShore Surely, I guess that my example proves that it also can be trascendental, don't know if that was obvious though.

Comment: It certainly can be transcendental over $K$.  I'm pretty sure it will be whenever $y$ is transcendental over $K(x)$.